# Servicio Web SOAP, ocultar

Tags: webservice, soap

Tengo la siguiente duda y no he encontrado nada claro.

¿Puedo tener levantado un servicio web sin tenerlo visible para el público que pueda escuchar mi servidor? Y conectarme únicamente si tengo el WSDL, con el mapeo de los servicios.

Estoy usando javax, para levantar el servicio SOAP.

Un saludo.

Comment: ¿Por qué no simplemente configuras la seguridad del contenedor?

Comment: Muchos toman la tarea de pasar el archivo wsdl a los clientes y tú servidor no tener público el wsdl y funciona!!

Comment: como "no se tiene publico el wsdl"? esto me valdría, un saludo y muchas gracias

Comment: Es posible no publicar el WSDL de tu servicio, solo es necesario el Endpoint para consumirlo si se conoce de antemano el contrato. Ahora, esta configuración es diferente para cada contenedor, cual usas tu??

Comment: Estoy usando:
Endpoint.publish("direccion", implementación);